# Which linux server distro to use for tomcat?

Tags: linux, tomcat, webserver

ubuntu 9.04, fedora 11, redhat...
what are the differences from a web server/development standpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to choose linux distros based on whichever ones have the most help available online.  I'd probably go with CentOS or Ubuntu for that reason.

Comment: went with ubuntu. with all the online help available, not looking back

Answer (score 6):

None. They differ only in how they package things, but they're all essentially the same - same operating system, same software. Some people get quite emotional about this choice, but I've used several, and there's nothing to pick between them these days.

Answer (score 1):

For tomcat there is not any difference but as a server: Ubuntu is more cutting edge in terms of kernel and packages. Ubuntu package management is superior and easier. If you will prefer Ubuntu then use server edition it is optimized as a server. CentOS is said to be solid but I haven't got much experience with it. If you are considering a virtual server different distros have different level of support for different virtualization technologies just keep it in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever your hardware vendor is happy to support. If you're serious about running a production system, you will use a supported OS.

Having said that, most vendors don't officially support Centos, however it is sufficiently similar (i.e. almost identical) to Redhat Enterprise that they ignore the difference.

Your code might run anywhere, but your hardware vendor's tools probably won't. You'll want to use those.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to linux, then I defiantly recommend Ubuntu.  You can be up and running in now time with apt-get.

Comment: as you can with fedora or half a dozen other distros.

Comment: I agree, but in my experience no other distro has the community support plus the ease of use that Ubuntu enjoys.  For example, you install Debian, and you have no repos defined by default (if memory servers).  I new user would have a difficult time getting around this.

On a side note, I was unaware that fedora supported apt-get out of the box.

Comment: fedora doesn't use apt-get, it uses yum, which IMHO is far superior.  I've always had problems with dependencies when using ubuntu's apt-get repos.  Fedora "just works".  YMMV